# Learning the basics to query in Splunk

Tags: real-time, splunk, documentation-generation, log-analysis

I am just starting to learn how to work on Splunk. Where can I find the tutorials to learn from the basics for real-time log analysis and generating reports. I tried looking up on google and youtube but, It is somewhat complex for me. Is there a dummy guide where I can start reading or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend taking the free Splunk Fundamentals I course at https://www.splunk.com/en_us/training/free-courses/splunk-fundamentals-1.html.